# remove old versions from pkg.go.dev

Tags: go

I have this Go package on GitHub. and on GitHub I've delete old version tags. but on:
`https://pkg.go.dev/example.com/username/pkg` it still showing those old versions.

I'm wondering how to completely delete those old package from `pkg.go.dev`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go module versions are immutable: you cannot invalidate them by simply removing tags, because if you then reused those tags you would cause [checksum mismatches](https://golang.org/ref/mod#checksum-database) for existing users.

Instead, you can use the [`retract` directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-retract) in your `go.mod` file to warn users to avoid versions in a specific range, and to cause the `go` command not to add new dependencies on those versions by default.